# Why $L(f,P_n) \leq \frac{b^2}2 \leq U(f, P_n)$ for $f(x)=x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm reading the Integrals chapter in Spivak's Calculus, he's taking integrals using lower and upper sums for equal intervals, often saying that it is *clear* that $L(f,P_n) \leq a \leq U(f, P_n)$ where $a$ is the limit to which the upper and lower sums are approaching as $n$ becomes very large, $n$ is the number of equal intervals.

For example, for $f(x)=x$, he's finding explicit formulas for the sums using the Gauss sum formula:

$$L(f,P_n)=\frac{n-1}n\cdot \frac{b^2}{2}$$

$$L(f,P_n)=\frac{n+1}n\cdot \frac{b^2}{2}$$

both are approaching $\frac{b^2}{2}$ for large $n$.

Then he says:

> It is clear, first of all, that
>
> $L(f,P_n) \leq \frac{b^2}2 \leq U(f, P_n)$

How is it clear?

I've checked these particular functions for both sums, lower is increasing and upper is decreasing, hence the inequality is indeed true. Is that what he meant by *clear* or I'm missing something?

Comment: Please recheck the question

Comment: I've fixed the formulas for the sums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take the uniform subdivision $P_n$ of the interval $[0,b]$, i.e.
$$0<\frac{b}{n}<\frac{2b}{n}<\dots<\frac{(n-1)b}{n}<b$$ then
$$L(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{kb}{n}\cdot \frac{b}{n}=
\frac{b^2}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k=\frac{b^2}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{b^2}{2}.$$

Then it is *clear* that the inequality $n-1<n$ implies
$$L(f,P_n)< \frac{b^2}{2}.$$
Similarly, the inequality $n+1>n$ implies
$$U(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{kb}{n}\cdot \frac{b}{n}=\frac{b^2}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{b^2}{2}>\frac{b^2}{2}.$$